# load an imageView from xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to use a command like this:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x2);
```

where should I put in the file `main.xml` the following piece of code?

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/x2"
    android:src="@drawable/book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: in your layout xml of the activity which you set in setContentView(r.layout.<id>)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dheeresh Singh is ok.
main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/x2"
          android:src="@drawable/book"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to position the image in a different place, you can modify different attributes

```
 <ImageView 
              android:id="@+id/x2"
              android:src="@drawable/book"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"  <!--for example  -->
              android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="25dp" 
              android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
```

For more information about this, look at the android tutorials

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html (for ImageView attributes)
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html (for view info)

Excuse me for my english.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Set in your layout xml of the activity which you set in `setContentView(r.layout.<id>)`

please refer tutorial to set `setContentView`

[Android-A-beginner-s-guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102065/Android-A-beginner-s-guide)

Answer (score 0):

As described in [XML Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) developer guide you should create your `main.xml` under /res/layout/ and put `ImageView` inside one of [available layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/x2"
      android:src="@drawable/book"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```